# Old vs New Style Joins

Tags: postgresql, join

SQL gets processed in this order:

```
From,
Where,
Group By,
Having,
Select,
Order By
```

In the new style of syntax for joins (explicitly using the word join), why doesn't this work faster than using the old style of joins (listing tables and then using a where clause)?

From gets processed before Where, so why wouldn't the newer style of join be faster?

The way that I imagine it is like this:
If you use the old style syntax, you are looking at entire tables and then filtering out the results.

If you use the new style syntax, you are filtering out your results first before moving to a 2nd step.

Am I missing something?

Comment: `new` join syntax is not designed to be a performance booster, it is simply a cleaner syntax; nothing more. `old` syntax still provided joins but these get expressed in a cleaner way with the newer syntax. So I simply say that your expectation for the newer syntax is false.

Comment: BTW. As I remember, `JOIN` was introduced in the SQL-92, about 25 years ago, so it is very relatively "new".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you send a query to postgresql, it doesn't always do scanning, filtering, etc in the same order. It examines the query, the tables involved, any constraints or indexes that might be involved, and comes up with an execution plan. If you want to see the execution pan for a query, you can use `EXPLAIN`, and it will invoke the planner without actually executing the query. [Here's some documentation for `EXPLAIN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html).

You tagged your question for postgresql, but other RDBMSes have similar facilities for examining the query plan.

Comment: So when you think of SQL, you need to think of the processing order as how your query is created, but as far as efficiency and how everything is actually executed, that could be anyone's guess because it's up to the RDBMS, is this all correct?

Comment: More or less. Think of a SQL query as a description of what data you want, not a plan for how to get it. The planning part is up to the RDBMS.